# the difference between using Vertx "IAsyncResult" and "EventBus consumer"

Tags: java, vert.x

please can someone explain to me what is the difference between this methods:

```
vertx.evenbus().consumer("test", message -> {
  ..........
});
vertx.evenbus().send("test", res->{
...........
});
```

and:

```
public void test(Handler<AsyncResult<JsonObject>> resultHandler){
..........
}

test(res->{
..........
})
```

Comment: One is sent over the eventbus, the other one isn't. For the programmer, it may not look like a big difference (which is kind of the point of the whole system), but the eventbus version allows you to distribute the logic into different verticles among different machines, scale them independently, etc. On the other hand, the eventbus DOES add a bit of complexity, but that is often hidden from the programmer and often just a setup issue.

Comment: Thank **DaDaDom** for explaining, in term of the response time... etc. there is no difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vert.x the eventbus is what allows you to quickly build a distributed application without the trouble of knowing where the other services are running, and also allows you to scale by adding more verticles listening on a common address.

When you use the first piece of code you're in fact asking vert.x to locate anywhere on the cluster a node (which could be the same as the caller) that can handle that specific type of message `"test"`.

On the second snippet you're defining a handler or callback if you prefer for a local action, for example what to do once a JSON object is read from a file.